# How can I add another row of text to the bottom of a forest plot made with forestplot?

Tags: r, plot, grid, draw, r-forestplot

I have created a forest plot using the forestplot package:
[image]

As you can see, the list of heterogeneity statistics in the final row of the first column is quite long, and it widens the column. I would like to remove this text from the labeltext argument (where I put it to generate the above plot, making the first column wider) and draw it once, separately, so it appears where it is but it extends under the other columns without making the first one wider.

I know I can use something like this to draw what I am looking for:

```
grid.text("test", x=unit(?????), y=unit(?????), rot=0,
          gp=gpar(col="red"))
```

**How can I get the location of the start of the first cell of the final row, underneath 'Overall'?**

Is there some way I can get the width of the entire plot so I can then find x by subtracting half the width from the middle of the viewport?

If anybody knows a better way of going about this, please let me know.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput` and the packages you have used?

Comment: Hi Quinten, I am using the package forestplot. I generated the above plot through somewhat elaborate means, using a custom CI function, playing around with fonts, and other things that it probably wouldn't help to share at this stage. I also feel like my data are basically irrelevant. My question more relates to the package forestplot and how one could draw text using grid in the location I have specified without including the text in the labeltext argument of the forestplot function, regardless of the data and the way the aesthetic features of the plot have been customised.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grid.text` where you need to specify `npc` in the units of the grid like this:

```r
library(forestplot)
cochrane_from_rmeta <- structure(list(mean  = c(NA, NA, 0.578, 0.165, 0.246, 0.700, 0.348, 0.139, 1.017, NA, 0.531), 
                                      lower = c(NA, NA, 0.372, 0.018, 0.072, 0.333, 0.083, 0.016, 0.365, NA, 0.386),
                                      upper = c(NA, NA, 0.898, 1.517, 0.833, 1.474, 1.455, 1.209, 2.831, NA, 0.731)),
                                 .Names = c("mean", "lower", "upper"), 
                                 row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
                                 class = "data.frame")

tabletext <- cbind(c("", "Study", "Auckland", "Block", "Doran", "Gamsu", "Morrison", "Papageorgiou", "Tauesch", NA, "Summary"),
                   c("Deaths", "(steroid)", "36", "1", "4", "14", "3", "1", "8", NA, NA),
                   c("Deaths", "(placebo)", "60", "5", "11", "20", "7", "7", "10", NA, NA),
                   c("", "OR", "0.58", "0.16", "0.25", "0.70", "0.35", "0.14", "1.02", NA, "0.53"))

forestplot(cochrane_from_rmeta, labeltext = tabletext, 
             is.summary = c(rep(TRUE, 2), rep(FALSE, 8), TRUE),
             clip = c(0.1, 2.5), 
             xlog = TRUE, 
             col = fpColors(box = "royalblue",
                            line = "darkblue",
                            summary = "royalblue"))
x <- unit(.05, 'npc')
y <- unit(.05, 'npc')
grid.text('A test text', x, y, gp = gpar(fontsize=10, font = 3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Quinten, thanks for responding. This doesn't solve the issue, unfortunately. I want to position the text so it is aligned precisely with the text in the column above. This would involve finding a way to get the exact x co-ordinate of the first column and the exact y co-ordinate of the row of interest. I would like to achieve this without using a magic number, because I am using forestplot() in my own function, with different data each time I use it. This means I am looking for a solution that will work regardless of the number of rows and the horizontal dimensions of the plot.

Comment: The solution may be somewhere in the source code for forestplot. This function prints the labels one row at a time, but I don't know how I'd get the co-ordinates they're being printed at: https://rdrr.io/github/gforge/forestplot/src/R/private.R#sym-prFpPrintLabels.